# How to get a TextView id from a custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom adapter for my ListView which has multiple TextViews. I want to set an onItemClickListener to my ListView and extract text out of the TextViews. I tried using this:

```
String s =(String) ((TextView) mListView.findViewById(R.id.myNr)).getText();
```

but as expected by default it always returns the values from the first list item! (I guess because it doesn't specify the item id from the list)

I also tried this:

```
String s =  (((TextView) mListView.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt)).
                          findViewById(R.id.myNr)).toString();
```

didn't work! Any suggestions?

This is implemented under the following function:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, 
                        int myItemInt, long mylng) {

             // String s statements

}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the full code:

```
 mListView_myentries.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, 
                        int myItemInt, long mylng) {

                    String workRequestSelected = (String) ((TextView) mListView_myentries.findViewById(R.id.work_request)).getText();
                    String activitySelected = (String) ((TextView) mListView_myentries.findViewById(R.id.activity)).getText();
                    String statusSelected = (String) ((TextView) mListView_myentries.findViewById(R.id.status)).getText();
                    String workRequestDescSelected = (String) ((TextView) mListView_myentries.findViewById(R.id.desc)).getText();
                    String actualHoursString = (String) ((TextView) mListView_myentries.findViewById(R.id.actual_hours)).getText();

}
```

Comment: Not positive about this, but if you give each individual TextView within the ListView an 'id', you can call that from your code.

Comment: @Harsh did you solve your issue ?

Comment: No. As I said it always returns the values from the first item in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView,int myItemInt, long mylng) {
             String s =(String) ((TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.myNr)).getText();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did before. It always gets the values of the first list item.

Comment: can you post your adapter class here

Comment: I just did. Please have a look

Comment: here is my sample activity with BaseAdapter and ItemClickListner implementation which successfully give desire output by using myView to fetch textView   http://pastebin.com/9iwdBm6y

Comment: Another code with ArrayAdapter check out here , working fine at my end http://pastebin.com/Smr4QtbG

Comment: Yes! I was using my `ListView` to locate the id, instead I should be using a view that is taken as input parameter by onItemClickListener. Thanks a lot for your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfect for me, however when i called my listContacts(listview) directly it always gave me the first record but when i called the view passed in to me it worked like a charm.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    String item = (((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtVwConID)).getText().toString());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If you have an question about my code ill post more here